# Is there an equivalent to Arch Linux's NETCFG for Debian?

Tags: debian

I have installed Debian Squeeze (minimal -- no DE) and I would like to connect to my network (via wireless) via command line. I have used Arch Linux before and I really liked the simplicity of `netcfg` which I used to connect to my network.

Is there an equivalent tool/program available in Debian that I can use?

Answer (score 2):

To connect to wireless via command line, the simplest thing is to install and use the wicd-curses package.

In alternative, you should fight with wpa_supplicant configuration files.

Comment: -1 i hate wicd. it *interferes* with the network configuration files (/etc/network/interfaces in debian). maybe that's why you wrote 'fight' and not 'customize'? the syntax of that file is pitifully easy, is it not?

Comment: there's also wicd-cli that might worth a shot

Answer (score 2):

On a machine where the network configuration doesn't change often, you can set it in `/etc/network/interfaces`. This file is documented in the [`interfaces(5)`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=interfaces&sektion=5) man page. Install the [wireless-tools](http://packages.debian.org/wireless-tools) and [wpasupplicant](http://packages.debian.org/wpasupplicant) packages to manage wireless interfaces. The wpasupplicant documentation has information on what to add to `/etc/network/interfaces`.

On a laptop where you need to set the wifi connection parameters anew for each network, it's a lot easier to use either Network Manager (which has no good command line client that I know of) or [wicd, which does](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30533/is-there-an-equivalent-to-arch-linuxs-netcfg-for-debian/30534#30534).

Comment: It's also possible to get by with only wpa_supplicant, which besides the static configuration files also provides command interfaces like `wpa_cli` and `wpa_gui` for dynamic configuration and switching between networks.  I use it because I prefer not being dependent on a GUI for network access.

Answer (score 1):

[ceni](http://manual.aptosid.com/en/inet-ceni-en.htm) is a good alternative, though it's not in the repo.

Answer (score 1):

Coming from Debian I had some trouble getting netcfg to do my bidding. 
I found it easier in debian just using wpa_supplicant something along the lines of

in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa.conf
```

and /etc/wpa.conf contains the meat of the wifi connection:

```
network={
  ssid="myssid"
  proto=RSN
  key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
  pairwise=CCMP TKIP
  group=CCMP TKIP
  psk="mywifi preshared key in clear"
}
```

you can have several network definitions. I use it for basic roaming.

The psk in clear text in not ideal. you can mitigate it by giving your conf file  a 600 permission. There is also the possibility to store a hash of the key. Check the man wpa_supplicant for more details.

Finally this sets up a system wide network profile which is exactly my use case (headless wireless appliance). Wicd and the like are also able to handle user network profiles.

As a side note: it is possible to install and use network manager on the command line only. check man nmcli . this may or may not fit your need.

Answer (score 0):

There's a netcfg package listed [here](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=netcfg), have you tried installing it? or is it different from the arch netcfg?

Comment: If you follows one of the links (for the various Debian versions) you get the following description: *Warning: This package is intended for the use in building debian-installer images only. Do not install it on a normal Debian system.*

Comment: It also appears to be an old version.